# How do you edit appsettings.json in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, microservices, amazon-eks

When running microservices in AWS using their EKS platform.  There are environment variables with secrets for most of the services, but some of the microservices also need to use json config files (appsettings.json).  It works fine once deployed.

How do you edit these config files in EKS without having to redeploy?

Thanks!

Comment: I saw an article that you can use ConfigMaps which you can edit via kubectl,  The article said secrets are also an option if the data is sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Once you deploy some application, it has all its dependencies loaded up in the place let's say in the container running in K8s.

Kubectl cp from local to the Pod is something you can try, I guess that should help.

```
kubectl cp /local/path namespace/podname:path/to/directory
```